# systemd tries to mount nfs share before correct interface is up

Tags: networkmanager, systemd-mount

On a Rocky8.8 server I want to mount an nfs share defined in `etc/fstab`.

```
admin1:/srv/export/opt/cluster          /opt/cluster    nfs     _netdev        0 0
```

The server have two network cards: `eno1` (ethernet) and `ib0` (infiniband)

The issue is that `ib0` seems to be ready before `eno1` according to NetworkManager logs and I want the nfs share to be mounted using `eno1`.

I tried to prevent `ib0` to have a default route: `nmcli connection modify ib0 ipv4.never-default yes` and I've overriden NetworkManager-wait-online.service as such:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -q
```

Anyway it seems that as soon as `ib0` is ready, systemd tries to mount the nfs share and it fails.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257888/systemd-wait-for-network-interface-to-be-up-before-running-service) help?