# Prevent systemd timer to run on a metered connection

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I have a systemd timer that runs every 10 minutes to download my email with `offlineimap`.  The problem is that i sometimes get a big amount of mail, or big attachments, and in the meantime i might be on the road using my phone’s metered connection.

Right now i have a custom script that queries the currently active connection using `nmcli` and checks if it is a metered one.  If so, it doesn’t run `offlineimap` at all.

My question is, can systemd timers do the same?  Something along these lines:

```
[Timer]
OnUnitInactiveSec=10m
RunOnMetered=no
```

Comment: I do use a service unit; the timer actually starts a oneshot service.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear, what I meant was that you'd actually need an additional unit like [`systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.html) and try to do [something like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212890/22142)  but you still have to use an external tool (like `nmcli`) to detect whether the connection via certain interface is metered as afaik you cannot do this systemd-only. That's why I said it's not going to be less complicated.

Answer (score 4):

You first need a Unit to depend upon which indicates whether the connection is or is not metered, like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check if the current connection is metered

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=check-metered-connection.sh
```

The `check-metered-connection.sh` is a simple dbus check:

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/bash

metered_status=$(dbus-send --system --print-reply=literal \
        --system --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
          /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager \
          org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
          string:org.freedesktop.NetworkManager string:Metered \
          | grep -o ".$")

if [[ $metered_status =~ (1|3) ]]; then
  echo Current connection is metered
  exit 1
else 
  exit 0
fi
```

Then your Units would depend on that service and you are good to go, like:

```
Requires=unmetered-connection.service
After=unmetered-connection.service
```

Somebody already thought about that and was kind enough to publish the code on Github, see [jdorel/systemd-metered-connection-dependency](https://github.com/jdorel/systemd-metered-connection-dependency) for the full code.

**All code samples here are not mine but copied verbatim from the linked repository**. Just copied here for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

This is in addition to marc's answer:

A downside to using `unmetered-connection.service` is that Systemd will consider it "failed" when you have a metered connection, which will cause `systemctl status` to report "degrade" even though nothing has really gone wrong. This might be okay with you, but if you don't like it, I've got an alternate solution.

---

The trick is to use a quite new option `ExecCondition=` ([SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41067756/5637701), [`man systemd.service`](https://manned.org/systemd.service.5#:%7E:text=After%3D%20ordering%20constraints.-,ExecCondition%3D,-Optional%20commands%20that)) in your `.service` file. It does require Systemd v243 or later, which you can check with `systemctl --version`.

This option allows running an arbitrary command, so you can actually check whatever you want very conveniently. We will reuse `check-metered-connection.sh` from [jdorel/systemd-metered-connection-dependency](https://github.com/jdorel/systemd-metered-connection-dependency) for this example.

Add the following code to your unit:

```ini
# only run when system is on an unmetered connection
# requires https://github.com/jdorel/systemd-metered-connection-dependency
[Service]
ExecCondition=check-metered-connection.sh
```

Assuming your service is a system unit (as opposed to a user unit; for difference see [`man systemd.unit`](https://manned.org/systemd.unit.5)) named `offlineimap.service`, this would be a drop-in configuration file at `/etc/systemd/system/offlineimap.service.d/only-on-unmetered.conf`.

And don't forget to run `[sudo] systemctl [--user] daemon-reload` after you're done.

---

P.S.

Be careful that there are several ways Systemd allows you to make customisations, which may all appear to achieve the same thing, but are subtly different. Unless you are extremely familiar with Systemd, I would ***highly recommend*** spending some time reading `man systemd.unit` before modifying anything. But here are some general tips:

1. ***Do not*** directly modify anything installed under `/usr/lib/systemd`. These are usually managed by your package manager and can possibly be reset to default after an update.
2. For small changes (like this), prefer drop-in configuration files (which amend) over copying the entire unit to `/etc/systemd` or `~/.config/systemd` (which override). This makes sure your unit is still updated by the package manager (when for example, the unit receives additional hardening). Again, refer to `man systemd.unit` for more information on this.

Also, this method makes changes to the service instead of the timer (even if you use a drop-in configuration file), which may not be ideal if other units depend on the service without this new unmetered restriction. In such cases, it would be a good idea to create a new custom unit-timer pair by copying to a different name, then only making changes on your custom service.